# problems with update statement in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I have created a database using SQLite. I want to update the value of a "features" column( type Blob)...but i do not know how to write the "update" statement .
This is what i tried:

```
    try {
        stat = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
    try {
        byte[] b = getFunction();
        stat.executeUpdate("update table set features="+b);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
```

i get the follwing error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: unrecognized token: "[B@13a317a"
```

so i guess that "b" is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one with PreparedStatement:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

try {
    byte[] b = getFunction();
    con = ...;
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("update table set features=?");
    stmt.setBytes(1, b);
    stmt.executeUpdate();

    con.commit();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    //handle exception (consider con.rollback()) and con maybe null here)
}
finally {
    //close stmt and at least con here (all maybe null here)
}
```

Personally I am always using PreparedStatements. When you have to write a lot of this code then consider writing some Utility-Classes to reduce Boilerplate-Code.

In particular you should consider writing Utilty-Classes for null-safe calling methods on Connection, Statement and ResultSet methods when you are dealing with plain JDBC.

**EDIT**
What Thomas Jung wrote about preventing SQL Injections is another big pro for always using PreparedStatements. +1 for him :-)

Answer (score 5):

[B@13a317a looks like a array to string result (b.toString() in this case). You should use a prepared statement for the blob like:

```
update table set features=?
```

An example is [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/BlobJDBCdealswithBinaryData.htm).

Generally, you should never create a SQL by concatenating strings. This is the recipe for SQL injection problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
 stat.executeUpdate("update table set features="+b[0].toString());
```

you have to use +

Comment: sorry, spelling mistake, i used "+"

Comment: you have also set a array try b[0]

Comment: Won't work.  `byte[].toString()` doesn't return the `X'...'` format that SQLite expects.