# How to Overwrite BLOB FILE in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, blob

I want to update or overwrite my blob file, I have picture field in my database i can only add image but i can't update it.

Here is my code for updating fields:

```
 try{

        String value1=txtID.getText();
        String value2=txtFirst.getText();
        String value3=txtLast.getText();
        String value4=txtUser.getText();
        String value5=txtPass.getText();
        Object value6=cmbType.getSelectedItem();
        Object value7=cmbStatus.getSelectedItem();
        String value8=txtEmail.getText();

        String sql="Update Account SET ID='"+value1+"', Fname='"+value2+"', Lname='"+value3+"',Email='"+value8+"', Username='"+value4+"', "
        + "Password='"+value5+"',Type='"+value6+"',Status='"+value7+"' WHERE ID='"+value1+"' ";

        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        int updateCount = pst.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data has been Updated");

    }

    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

    finally{
        try{
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
    }
```

can someone suggest code for updating or overwriting a blobfile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189637/problems-with-update-statement-in-sqlite Google is your friend

Comment: This is open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use `?`s in your SQL statement instead of concatenating the parameters into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PreparedStatement` API wisely to set the parameters after you create it using `SQL` with `placeholders` '?'. Please don't use concatenation operator while creating queries with dynamic parameters on the fly.

This will not work

```
    String sql="Update Account SET ID='"+value1+"',
    Fname='"+value2+"', Lname='"+value3+"',Email='"
    +value8+"', Username='"+value4+"', "+ "Password='"
    +value5+"',Type='"+value6+"',Status='"+value7+"'
     WHERE ID='"+value1+"' ";
```

You are concatenating variables of `Object` type in the above `SQL` string.That's not fair.

This way is to go

```
String sql = String sql="Update Account SET ID=?, Fname=?, Lname=?,Email=?, Username=?,  Password=?,Type=?,Status=? WHERE ID=? ";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.preparedStatement(sql);
//set all the values one by one by calling the appropriate
//setter methods based on field type
pstmt.setString(1,value1);
....
....
//Set the Blob to be updated
pstmt.setBlob(BLOB_INDEX,BLOB_OBJ);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can i improve it?

Comment: My answer explains how you should improve. Try to keep it as reference and do changes in it

Comment: i have a little problem what will i put in BLOB_INDEX, and BLOB_OBJ

Comment: put the index of the BLOB columns and set the Blob object you have to update